# Cypher query gives java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

When I type this query in the Neo4j shell:

```
MATCH (b:PHARMA)-[r:HAS_DONATED]->(a:DOCTOR)
WITH a,r,b, r.DECL_AVANT_MONTANT as total, COUNT(r) as count
MERGE (b)-[:RELATIONSHIP {
totalDECL: total,
numberDECL: count
}]->(a);
```

I receive this message:

```
Error occured in server thread; nested exception is: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Any idea on how to get around this?

Comment: What is the sense of `COUNT(r) as count`? The result will be always **1** because you use `r` in `WITH` clause.

Comment: PHARMA nodes and DOCTOR nodes can have multiple HAS_DONATED relationships. I'm trying to create a single relationship that sums it up. It has to contain the number of HAS_DONATED relationships and the sum of the donations amount. Is that clear?

Comment: If you run this query: `MATCH (b:PHARMA)-[r:HAS_DONATED]->(a:DOCTOR)
WITH a,r,b, r.DECL_AVANT_MONTANT as total, COUNT(r) as count RETURN count(*)` you'll see that you would MERGE _a lot_ of data, that's why your transaction size fills all available heap and blows up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by using this query:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 2000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:c:/sunshine.anonymes.csv" AS line
FIELDTERMINATOR ','
MATCH (b:DOCTOR {ID: line.BENEF_PS_ID})
MATCH (a:PHARMA {NAME: line.LABO})
MERGE (a)-[r:IS_LINKED_TO]->(b)
ON CREATE SET r.numberDECL = 1, r.totalDECL = toINT(line.DECL_AVANT_MONTANT)
ON MATCH SET r.numberDECL = r.numberDECL +1, r.totalDECL = line.totalDECL + r.totalDECL;
```

Basically, I'm creating the relationship during the csv import and updating the properties throughout the process.

Thank you for your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it helps. But here is repaired Cypher query for your case:

```
MATCH (b:PHARMA)-[r:HAS_DONATED]->(a:DOCTOR)      
WITH a, b, SUM(r.DECL_AVANT_MONTANT) as total, COUNT(r) as count   
MERGE (b)-[:RELATIONSHIP {   
totalDECL: total,   
numberDECL: count  
}]->(a);
```